# Number of cosets and the their representations in quotient groups of the form $(Z\times Z)/\langle (a,b) \rangle$ for different pairs of $(a,b)$

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

I asked an earlier question ([Finding elements of infinite order in quotient groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4438865/finding-elements-of-infinite-order-in-quotient-groups?noredirect=1#comment9295156_4438865)) and I realize I am having trouble understanding the quotient groups in the questions posted.  Hence I am posting a separate more basic question related to it.

The quotient group $\mathbb{Z}/\langle n \rangle$, the cosets are of the form $\mathbb{Z}/\langle n \rangle=\{0 + \langle n \rangle, 1 + \langle n \rangle, \ldots  ,(n-1) + \langle n \rangle\}$, and there are $n$ of them.

In the case of $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/\langle (a,b) \rangle$, if $a=b$, then there should be $a^2$ number of cosets?  They are of the form $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/\langle (a,a) \rangle=\{(0,0)+ (\langle a \rangle \times \langle a \rangle), \ldots ,(a-1,a-1)+ (\langle a \rangle \times \langle a \rangle)\}$

if $a\neq b$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$, then there should be $ab$ number of cosets in $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/\langle (a,b) \rangle$ The cosets are of the form $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/\langle (a,b) \rangle=\{(0,0)+ (\langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle), \ldots ,(a-1,b-1)+ (\langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle)\}$

Finally if $a\neq b$ and $gcd(a,b)\neq 1$, then can I reduce $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a'}{b'}$, where $gcd(a',b')= 1$.  So the number of cosets in the quotient group $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/\langle (a,b) \rangle$ is $a'b'$ and they are of the form $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/\langle (a,b) \rangle=\{(0,0)+ (\langle a' \rangle \times \langle b' \rangle), \ldots ,(a'-1,b'-1)+ (\langle a' \rangle \times \langle b' \rangle)\}$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In all cases, there are infinitely many cosets. Try the explicit example $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\langle(1, 1)\rangle$. You suggest above that there should be only one coset, the trivial one, but I encourage you to find others.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Sorry i just saw this now..  In the case of $(a,b) + \langle (1,1) \rangle$ would have finite order if and only if $(a,b)\in \langle (1,1) \rangle$  or equivalently $(a,b)\in \{(1,1), (2,2), \ldots,(t,t)\}$.  Am I understanding the notation correctly?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese also, in the case of $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/\langle (1,1) \rangle$, the cosets for this quotient group are $[(0,0)]+\langle (1,1) \rangle$, $[(0,1)]+\langle (1,1) \rangle$, $[(1,0)]+\langle (1,1) \rangle$ and both $[(0,1)]+\langle (1,1) \rangle$, $[(1,0)]+\langle (1,1) \rangle$ has infinite order while $[(0,0)]+\langle (1,1) \rangle$ is the only one that have finite order.

Comment: If $(a, b) + \langle(1, 1)\rangle$ has finite order, then $(a, b) \in \langle(1, 1)\rangle$, so $(a, b) + \langle(1, 1)\rangle = (0,0) + \langle(1, 1)\rangle$, the identity element of $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\langle(1,1)\rangle$. The elements $(1, 0) + \langle(1, 1)\rangle$ and $(0, 1) + \langle(1, 1)\rangle$ do indeed have infinite order. Note that $(0, 1) + \langle(1, 1)\rangle = -(1,0) + \langle(1, 1)\rangle$, so you can actually write every element of $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\langle(1, 1)\rangle$ as $(k, 0) + \langle(1, 1)\rangle$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese each coset is of the form $[(a,b)]=(a,b) + \langle (1,1) \rangle=(a+t, b+t$, where $t\in Z$.  Also $(1,1)\in \langle (1,1) \rangle$ and $(1,1) + \langle (1,1) \rangle$ as a coset element have finite order, but since $(1,1)=(1,0)+(0,1)$, both coset elements $(1,0,) + \langle (1,1) \rangle$ and $-(1,0)+ \langle (1,1) \rangle$ have infinite order.  As another example, for the case of the quotient group $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/\langle (2,2) \rangle$, $(1,1)\notin \langle (2,2) \rangle$, because $(1,1)\notin (2t,2t)$ for any $t\in \mathbb{Z}$, but...

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese ...but $(1,1) + \langle (2,2) \rangle\equiv -(1,1) + \langle (2,2) \rangle\equiv (0,0) + \langle (2,2) \rangle$.  Am I interpreting these notations correctly?  If I am correct, can I also ask you about whether the number of cosets for the two variable cases is the same as in the one variable case.

Comment: $(1, 1) + \langle (2, 2)\rangle$ and $(0, 0) + \langle(2,2)\rangle$ are different cosets because $(1, 1) \not\in\langle(2,2)\rangle = \{(2t, 2t) \mid t \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese can I conclude from what we have discussed so far that if in the quotient group $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/\langle (a,b) \rangle$, and for any coset $[(a',b')]=(a',b') + \langle (a,b) \rangle$. If $(a',b')\in \langle (a,b) \rangle=\{(at,bt)|\forall t \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, then the coset $(a',b')\in \langle (a,b) \rangle$ is of finite order.  Otherwise if $(a',b')\notin \langle (a,b) \rangle$, then the coset $(a',b') + \langle (a,b) \rangle$ is of infinite order.

Comment: If $(a', b') \in \langle(a, b)\rangle$, then $(a', b') + \langle(a, b)\rangle = (0,0) + \langle(a, b)\rangle$, the identity of $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\langle(a,b)\rangle$. If $(a', b') \not\in \langle(a, b)\rangle$, then $(a', b') + \langle(a, b)\rangle$ is a non-identity element of $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\langle(a, b)\rangle$; it could have finite order or infinite order. For example, $(1, 1) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle$ has order two in $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/\langle(2,2)\rangle$, while $(1, 0) + \langle(2, 2)\rangle$ has infinite order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136004/discussion-between-michael-albanese-and-seth-mai).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I am not sure where you are.  I am in NYC time zone.  It seems like we keep missing each other with replies. I think I understand enough about the notation to resolve the issue of order of elements.  I will either make another post about the issue of counting number of cosets or ask someone else in person.  I saw a similar question in two different algebra textbooks and there are issues of subtle  mistaken understanding of notations like $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/\langle (a,b) \rangle$ is not the same as ...

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese ...$(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/(\langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle)$ or if $G=(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z})$ and $N=\{(2a,3b)\in G| \forall a, b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, the cosets for such quotient group would mean different thing for the quotient group as a whole.  Thank you so much for taking the time out to answer my questions.  I really appreciate your patience.